# SQL Noob. "Foreign Key Constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have viewed the other topics with this post, and tried to adapt my scripts to them, but to no avail. So I am posting here.

I have two tables, subjects and students. Within these, there are two primary keys (subject_id and student_id), refer to the image for a [full view of the two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P6e4.jpg) (done in phpmyadmin).

I am aiming to create a third table which contains entry_id (Primary Key), subject_id (FK), subject_name(FK), subjectexamboard(FK), student_id(FK) and studentfirstname(FK).

Here is the code which I've tried to run on phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE TABLE entries3(
entry_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_id INT NOT NULL,
subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
subjectExamBoard VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
studentFirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
studentLastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (entry_id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (subject_name) REFERENCES subjects(subject_name),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (subjectExamBoard) REFERENCES subjects(exam_board),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (studentFirstName) REFERENCES students(first_name),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (studentLastName) REFERENCES students(last_name));
```

Thanks for any help, please go easy on me as I'm very new to SQL.

Comment: The constraints on names are unnecessary, as are the columns.

Comment: I removed the [tag:sql-server] tag. MySQL has `AUTO_INCREMENT` syntax, but Microsoft SQL Server does not.

Comment: As @DanBracuk said, you are creating unnecessary redundancies by having `studentFirstName`, `studentLastName`, `subjectExamBoard`, and `subject_name`. All those columns can be obtained through a join. You may want to revisit your design

Answer (score 0):

Check each column pair for your FK constraint, they should be the same data type

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That is **not** what you want to do. You want a query or a view.

What you are trying to do above breaks any kind of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Your entry table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE entries3 (
  entry_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject_id INT NOT NULL,
  student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (entry_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_entry_subjects FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_entry_students FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)
);
```

Then you query it with

```
select sub.*, stu.*
from entries3 as ent
  inner join subjects as sub 
    on ent.subject_id = sub.subject_id
  inner join students as stu 
    on ent.student_id = stu.student_id
```

Comment: Ah I see. I do not understand, but thank you very much for the help. I'll try it later! :)

Comment: Since you don't understand, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  The relevant cliché is, It's easier to do things well than twice.

Answer (score 0):

Should be   CONSTRAINT   name_of_constrainT  FOREIGN KEY

assuming that your name are valid

```
   CREATE TABLE entries3(
  entry_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject_id INT NOT NULL,
  subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  subjectExamBoard VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  studentFirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  studentLastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (entry_id),
  CONSTRAINT subject_id_fk      FOREIGN KEY  (subject_id)       REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  CONSTRAINT subject_name_fk    FOREIGN KEY  (subject_name)     REFERENCES subjects(subject_name),
  CONSTRAINT subjectExamBoar_fk FOREIGN KEY  (subjectExamBoar)  REFERENCES subjects(exam_board),
  CONSTRAINT student_id_fk      FOREIGN KEY  (student_id)      REFERENCES students(student_id),
  CONSTRAINT studentFirstName_fk FOREIGN KEY (studentFirstName) REFERENCES students(first_name),
  CONSTRAINT studentLastName_fk  FOREIGN KEY (studentLastName)  REFERENCES students(last_name));
```

Comment: you forgot to specify the column after `FOREIGN KEY`

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Key Constraint name can not be the same as the attributes of the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve from third table. But if goal is just to show two tables together then just create a view.

```
CREATE view entries3 AS 
SELECT 
su.subject_id AS 'Subject_ID',
su.subject_name AS 'Subject_Name',
su.subjectexamboard AS 'Subject_Exam_Board'
st.student_id AS 'Student_ID',
st.studentfirstname AS 'Student_First_Name'
FROM subject su, student st;
```

Then query as

```
SELECT * from entries;
```